# Text/fonts display garbled after resume from hibernation

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, hibernate

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a primary ext4 partition (as a sole OS) and set the swap partition over double my RAM which was 3 GB (Swap partition is currently 10 GB).

Fonts and texts are just garbled after resuming from hibernation. I was wondering if there is an incompatibility with my graphic card driver or something else?

[image: This is the Snapshot of the current OS view]

I have the Intel GM45 display driver chipset for graphics.

```
 *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f6c00000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:efe8(size=8)

  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6b00000-f6bfffff

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Linux amir-labtop 3.2.0-37-generic-pae #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:51:02 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading my RAM modules to dual channel (8GB) on my Inspiron laptop, the persisting problem seems to be gone away automatically after a couple of weeks. Therefore, I assume, the garbled font problem was basically nothing than a low memory allocation after hibernation (or generally any memory consuming task like using Matlab, etc).

Ubuntu automatically changed my 10 GB swap to 13 GB and all seems fine so far.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same error on my Lenovo X200 with intel graphics, too.

[According to this thread on Lenovo forums](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/x200s-Latest-64bit-Intel-Graphics-driver-corruption-after-resume/td-p/177220) it's an intel driver issue. I think we have to wait for the devs to fix it.

Comment: yup, i think that's right, I have tried to report the bug several times but nothing good have come out of this. Do you know any better (let's say more official ways) to report the problem to Ubuntu ?

Comment: check my new answer buddy ;)