# Hibernate altrnative tools in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Due to the persistent problem with garbling fonts after resuming hibernation in ubuntu (which remained unanswered in this thread [Original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256417/text-fonts-display-garbled-after-hibernation-resume))

; I would like to ask if there are other tool/ gnu packages which actually do the hibernate process in an alternative options for the ubuntu 12.04 official hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

I would be very suprised if such a tool really exists.

Searching on the get-deb site learned me there is no tool for such purposes. (And I Googled a lot ;) )

However, have you tried the suspend-mode in Ubuntu ? This option is more steady than hibernation I've learned over the several versions of Ubuntu.

Suspend writes your RAM-memory away to the disc and awakes very fast (within 15 seconds you're back online). In version (kernel 3.5) 12.10 this feature is a lot improved, so I feel you should try this option a time.

The downside of suspend is that it consumes a bit more energy (if that is an issue of course)